# Error while using columns achieved by aggregation of window function in case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, case, window-functions

I am learning SQL window functions as part of it solving the leet code average salary, department vs company, https://leetcode.com/problems/average-salary-departments-vs-company/

I have written a query using window functions

```
select left(pay_date,7) as month, department_id,
avg(amount) over (partition by left(pay_date,7), department_id) as dep_avg,
avg(amount) over(partition by left(pay_date,7)) as com_avg,
CASE 
    WHEN dep_avg = com_avg THEN 'same'
    else 'not same' end as comparision                               
from salary s
inner join employee e
on s.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Query works fine without case statement, but with case statement, it is giving an error

> Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'dep_avg' in 'field list'

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you using [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? That error is *not* a SQL Server error.

Comment: As for the error, you're trying to reference a column defined in the `SELECT` by its alias; you can't do that. You would need to repeat the expression, or use a CTE/subquery.

Comment: The alias of output column cannot be used in another output column expression. You may refer to it only in GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT()` on a `date` column?  `LEFT()` is a **string** function and dates should be stored using the appropriate date/time data type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to an alias defined in a select clause within the same select clause.  The reason is that the alias may not be available to use yet.  The easiest way out here is to use a subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LEFT(pay_date, 7) AS month, department_id,
           AVG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(pay_date, 7), department_id) AS dep_avg,
           AVG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(pay_date, 7)) AS com_avg
    FROM salary s
    INNER JOIN employee e
        ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id
)

SELECT month, department_id, dep_avg, com_avg,
       CASE WHEN dep_avg = com_avg THEN 'same' ELSE 'not same' END AS comparison
FROM cte;
```